# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Classes1

Tags: java

```
public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

    private static final String LOGCAT=null;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "school.db", null, 1);
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query,query1,query2;
        query="CREATE TABLE Teachers(Name TEXT, E_Mail VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR, Mob_No TEXT, Department TEXT)";
        query1="CREATE TABLE Students(Roll_No VARCHAR ,Name TEXT, E_Mail VARCHAR, Semester INTEGER, Mob_No TEXT, Department TEXT)";
        query2="CREATE TABLE Classes1(E_Mail VARCHAR, Assign_class VARCHAR)";
        //    query1="CREATE TABLE Subjects(Branch_Name TEXT ,Branch_Code VARCHAR, Semester INTEGER, Sub_Name VARCHAR, Sub_Code VARCHAR, Type TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.execSQL(query1);
        db.execSQL(query2);
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Teachers Created");
    }
```

It is showing that there is no such table exists. Classes1.. please clear my doubt

Comment: Table `Classes1` should be okay. Can you please show us the full exception trace? That would help us determine what the real problem is.

Comment: The issue has been resolved since i had uninstalled the app from mobile and then re-lauched it.  Also i came to know that if any changes are been made in Sqlite database, we have to uninstall it and then relaunch it to make changes effect.  Thanks for your attention Tamas. :)

Comment: I'm glad that you solved this problem :) I'm just wondering, is this reinstall really necessary? Probably deleting (renaming) the database file, and recreating it from scratch should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

asi se crea las tablas  xml en android studio

```
 <string name="db_v1">
    CREATE TABLE tbl_Lista(
          listaId INTEGER NOT NULL,
         nombre TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(listaId)
    );


   CREATE TABLE tbl_Item(
    itemId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    descripcion TEXT NOT NULL,
    checked INTEGER NOT NULL,
    listasId INTEGER NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(itemId)
    );
 FOREIGN  KEY (listasId)REFERENCES tbl_Lista(listaId)
</string>
```